# QML need to create component with bool property all list elements were within limits

Tags: qt, qml

I was thinking I need a component similar to ListModel, but I need to extend it to expose a readonly bool property such as "all list elements were within minimum and maximum limit" so I can do logic outside the component the determine certain things. How should I go about doing this extending a boolean property based on model's contents?

I guess naive way is to just add the qml property and do javascript loop on QML side to check all model contents but that might not be so good performance

Comment: Assuming you want to do this in pure QML, I'd suggest enclosing `ListModel` within an `Item`, then rewriting custom functions that call list model functions and updating your min/max flag whenever any data changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered `DelegateModel`? It allows you to create "views" on your `ListModel` so you can control what you want to be displayed via the `filterOnGroup` property.

It is rather difficult to comprehend, but, in the following example, I have a `ListModel` containing 5 cities. When you start changing the RangeSlider the 5 cities will be filtered based on the minimum/maximum population selected. This works by updating the boolean function filter on the `DelegateModel` to reflect the cities that are now visible.

```js
property var filter: model => model.pop >= rangeSlider.first.value
                           && model.pop <= rangeSlider.second.value
```

Here's the full code snippet:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQml.Models 2.15

Page {
    anchors.fill: parent
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Label { text: qsTr("States") }
        ListView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            model: DelegateModel {
                id: filterDelegateModel
                property int updateIndex: 0
                property var filter: model => model.pop >= rangeSlider.first.value
                                           && model.pop <= rangeSlider.second.value
                onFilterChanged: Qt.callLater(update)
                model: us_states
                groups: [
                    DelegateModelGroup {
                        id: allItems
                        name: "all"
                        includeByDefault: true
                        onCountChanged: {
                            if (filterDelegateModel.updateIndex > allItems.count) filterDelegateModel.updateIndex = allItems.count;
                            if (filterDelegateModel.updateIndex < allItems.count) Qt.callLater(update, filterDelegateModel.updateIndex);
                        }
                    },
                    DelegateModelGroup {
                        id: visibleItems
                        name: "visible"
                    }]
                filterOnGroup: "visible"
                delegate: Frame {
                    id: frame
                    width: ListView.view.width - 20
                    background: Rectangle {
                        color: (frame.DelegateModel.visibleIndex & 1) ? "#f0f0f0" : "#e0e0e0"
                        border.color: "#c0c0c0"
                    }
                    RowLayout {
                        width: parent.width
                        Text {
                            text: (frame.DelegateModel.visibleIndex + 1)
                            color: "#808080"
                        }
                        Text {
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            text: model.state
                        }
                        Text {
                            text: qsTr("pop: %1 M").arg((pop / 1000000).toFixed(2))
                        }
                    }
                }
                function update(startIndex) {
                    startIndex = startIndex ?? 0;
                    if (startIndex < 0) startIndex = 0;
                    if (startIndex >= allItems.count) {
                        updateIndex = allItems.count;
                        return;
                    }
                    updateIndex = startIndex;
                    if (updateIndex === 0) {
                        allItems.setGroups(0, allItems.count, ["all"]);
                    }
                    for (let ts = Date.now(); updateIndex < allItems.count && Date.now() < ts + 50; updateIndex++) {
                        let visible = !filter || filter(allItems.get(filterDelegateModel.updateIndex).model);
                        if (!visible) continue;
                        allItems.setGroups(updateIndex, 1, ["all", "visible"]);
                    }
                    if (updateIndex < allItems.count) Qt.callLater(update, updateIndex);
                }
                Component.onCompleted: Qt.callLater(update)
            }
        }
        Label { text: "Population Range" }
        RangeSlider {
            id: rangeSlider
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            from: 0
            to: 100000000
            first.value: 1
            first.onMoved: Qt.callLater(filterDelegateModel.update)
            second.value: 100000000
            second.onMoved: Qt.callLater(filterDelegateModel.update)
            stepSize: 1000000
            
        }
        Label { text: qsTr("Minimum %1 M").arg((rangeSlider.first.value / 1000000).toFixed(2))  }
        Label { text: qsTr("Maximum %1 M").arg((rangeSlider.second.value / 1000000).toFixed(2)) }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: us_states
        ListElement { state:"California"; pop: 39350000 }
        ListElement { state:"Texas"; pop: 28640000 }
        ListElement { state:"New York"; pop: 8380000 }
        ListElement { state:"Nevada"; pop: 3030000 }
        ListElement { state:"Las Vegas"; pop: 644000 }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://qmlonline.kde.org/?code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBARRggrsAxgazgJgHQCMArAFCiSyLJpZ4DCEAdjFBADYDOuhp508SVBkx4AMgEMAnhBQwuBHmXD8qCEGzwBZCABMApp27ESJAAriA5nrgBvEnAdxxjdAAtoHPADNgbNgC44MHEoPWZ7RwY2FBBGCWlZWwjHR2c3D29fAKCQsJhklLgJACMDWzgYPQAPGECARw4AFSgACgAiAGUYcUqONoBKOABfApTRYA4YADVgPQB3JMKloqkZGEy-AHVgHRhXQJYUPVHl+LWNtgAJPWALV1qKqCOTpZBdA0CAEQM9Cx69bT6NiLZagnaBHxsSpQb5sX7-QEGF6goKsMB6WCSODAZhwFBgHT-ACSjH0VUCAAZkaCwGiMTAsQA3EJwSHQwJvIFwAC8AD44JyDHhIGA4LzuXAoM4rB02DsMZkoJM8MzoscURrNVq4AAyHUC94aEVwAA8EqljBlcv0UDwHD06CYOhV4jV1OWTAAYr5oXRXNK9DpAkg8OhXWwJNCWvjCZV+u7XobAigOAB9Sb-DgJwoWVj4jiBADa2dBsPhlURbAA4nnRXZtZrwU4-ETKiAsw2NYxxCA9IE2uG2iXGy5ovoAEKSb5ecQoKEHJ7qzugpgMFDMP0BoMg5ca4BeOAtNkYst-CuGvAx4mk6pi5tsVt6duhmTMQbHmE-M8Ai9XyokskeXvR9n0ddcYAAbmHBt90PD9TwRX8CWvQCTWAttPDAt8qFDcNIwxaNkMqAAaVkfRPL9EKBS8iL0ADqn6KDd2WEZmIcIZiOgwoEPPIEaxkOsuLBbdGQmYBijhECOzYlJu17ftRI4cS4SHGShgAXS4j8AHlGH4-EFLEiS9FUzsgXLPs4E9KVex3Xcmy8Gyl2YuYdj2QJxkmGZ5hVWY5jwVzdlcOAAFpcCpGTinELBc1fbcACUHW6S04TsmTHTYaBAiPJy8B4n9qMU5S6JvKpdTgAhBgAfjgNoAGIvApRrGraOB+zqvQKU6zrTJkhximgG0X0yqB2vQClxvG3rd1Ytj4ogOYzkSes+ocQL3JyUJmACtzXCE5ZGmqeAVtWlJKhqbLHJ7PQ8so3ihSK4z6LKgBqCr41OwoMqy2q6oADgpAGAemtT9qWQ6ajS06lvWSE2G2IKF2eT6zqOjkLwzSowcKWbVoh47sdBc6HgaZp2hFQIAFICDgTQBjwEILBaFpjQAegqilOa5-o8BgCBvSqQMWhwfoPtO3GZq4iWtS8dd0BgYAmDxWiWgzWBnsGE7dzVmBnqAnW9aqmqKSYtjYNV7p1dK004ApQYDetiUTex82HcA8V0KfTDXxgTXCccP8SsAiVwykl9wNN1bQhgFAoEYSPJZkwO9YlN3qgT5dzeTx3uSdv3PtDjC7T0GB9LADgWgpUjC698PmFIwsBz8Np1MY7Hpc7LxoEPOF4DkIDPn+PBGAWlpGOV2Mg9vNCa9An3dX1QfKmH0fBjQ-u3qIE2J5Q6oXpe-PTt7uBHtSiUAEIPzgAAfa+yKhAjZ88KwYCPcjPzhb9KxoyeNbwQU2Bt0+ubc+p89CDEdMwHERwM5sSfsXUutYK7ZzJKRAgDcm5sDaKRNoYCW5ALYh3GCB5CK-2tjPFsRcsK+xwmGPw+FWiB1IighisCNREJRAwZQjA8h4FXBAcAvdAzBnWHQiM-xGG0TFuw5EHCShlBsBUNGtVTAQDAHOHoitGBwHigGVqHDdGWj0LKeUUAoZLCbBaK0pjswwwuAjDahxnIokcgIyk2Y+aBAIFzHxEVNQ+CVOsVURwvHZgCcqJg2hGTCNoXhCRb8H4fwst-QO0iUT2kgc6YJllvG+M5tmDJTo+GMCiTEkMYiGEJOhPlFJUiCmVDAB0YAAAvHJeTsyyORPI4Eijib1CaK0NomgcSgBiHAamtN6aM2ZlY4x1oFThKCa6I4cB2a5J8TzPmAshYi0GMMLp4hSg9KURdOApNBmaHEFUUZIBxk0zpjzaZLRZkmKGoU0kLo1SrI5r4zZ-NgCCx0MLUW+yUgS08jASs5jsTbhTOmbovQukTBgAAUThL2XEijMZ9jaHQV0+5oCMGAOINoEEghqMCAAZgAJyUq3lzUFpxkVoqfHkco2L-BtAhuIPoZKKa4D+gANgACw+MZUsCFLKMXHTgBytoAA5eYcAACa0BMCkvJWAQIf1KUAwZXI5l6K2VYoRTixVzJCQav5ZSikNr9VIsmFK41srTWcokFwKY8JeWasCCK0VnNxX7KGEAA)

I have refactored the above into a `FilterDelegateModel` reusable component. Feel free to check it out:

- https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-toolkit
- https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-toolkit/wiki/FilterDelegateModel

Comment: Hi, I believe your answer is unrelated to the OP's question, as he wants a boolean flag that is true when all data are within the desired range.

Comment: Hi @SMR, the intention of my answer is to set the boolean via setting the filter. Which is an function that returns a boolean. He also indicated there is some kind of minimum and maximum range. Without supplying any data, I had no choice but to supply my own. The boolean function supplied is in my filter function. If more information is supplied with actual data, I will change the data and filter function to reflect the OP's data.